# chrome packaged app image access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am having trouble accessing images in the chrome packaged app. These images are stored locally. Code works fine in the browser.

following image tag

```
   <img ng-src="pics/{{employee.pic}}">
```

I am using angularjs.

Thanks,
Niranjan

Answer (score 1):

See:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external

What you have to do is fetch the binary contents of the image with XMLHttpRequest as a blob, then convert that blob to an object URL, and that's the URL you set as the src attribute of the img. It's easier than it sounds, and the cited web page gives you the code.