# Is it possible to source a local file resource in an <img>?

Tags: google-chrome-app, local-files

I have a need to point my image tags at a directory that is not part of my app.

The use-case is that this is a kiosk app for which the assets are delivered via Dropbox. So, the user will need to configure the app by pointing the fileSystem object at the required Dropbox directory and then the app will use that directory to source its media.

The fileSystem `Entry` returns a path that looks like:
`~/Dropbox/and/so/on/and/so/forth`

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to use that either explicitly
a la

`<img src="~/Dropbox/and/so/on/and/so/fort/image.png"/>`

or via some hacky alternative like

`<img src="file:///users/someuser/Dropbox/and/so/on/and/so/forth"/>`

However all the various combinations I've tried produce a broken image - even though when I inspect the element and click on it in the console Chrome is able to view the image as a stand-alone entity, so I know the path is correct.

I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious, but can't find any documentation for how to correctly aim my resources at the file system.

Comment: It's not exactly the path you're going through, but couldn't you map this folder as a _virtual directory_ like we have in IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd expect that the `fileEntry.toURL()` method returns the `filesystem:..`-URL that can be used to directly embed the image in the page. However, that is not the case because of http://crbug.com/148788.

If you're certain that you can always access the filesystem after requesting permissions, the most efficient solution to embed an image from the user's filesystem is to use `blob:`-URLs. Here is an example without any error handling:

```js
// Within your app's code, somehow get a DirectoryEntry (or FileEntry):
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'openDirectory'
}, function(directoryEntry) {
    // Assume that the user has selected the directory containing the images.
    directoryEntry.getFile('path/to/img.png', function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            // url looks like "blob:chrome-extension%3A//[extensionid]/[uuid]"
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        });
    });
});
```

If you don't know the image path in advance, then you could either enumerate the items in the directory using a [`DirectoryReader`](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html#idl-def-DirectoryReader) (created using `directoryEntry.createReader()`), or directly prompt for the `FileEntry` (and use `fileEntry.file`, etc., to get the blob:-URL).

To try out the previous snippet, use the following as `manifest.json`

```js
{
  "name": "FS App",
  "version": "2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["directory"]}
  ]
}
```

`background.js`

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('main.html');
});
```

`main.html`

```html
<script src="main.js"></script> <!-- main.js = previous code -->
```

Create a directory that contains "path/to/img.png", load the app, launch the app and click on the just-created directory that contains that picture. You will see that the image is embedded in the app's document.

Comment: I think this is essentially the same as my answer (although yours is more detailed), but my documentation shows that URL has to be prefixed by webkit. Perhaps this requirement has been lifted in recent versions of Chrome.

Comment: @MarcRochkind Your answer suggested to do something along the lines of retrieving the data via XMLHttpRequest, then convert it to a `data:`-URL. That approach is fundamentally different from my suggested answer, which recommends to convert a `FileEntry` to a `File`, then generate a blob:-URL from it. I see that you've edited your answer since to briefly suggest my method, but using the prefixed `webkitURL` instead of `URL`. This object has been unprefixed since Chrome 23, so there is no point in teaching to use `webkitURL` instead of `URL`.

Comment: OK... nice to hear about the prefix.

Comment: looks like the winner to me... I'll implement later today and confirm that this is the *right answer... I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: that's truly perfect! I read each entry from sandboxed file system until  (very time consuming) until now!
Now just reading the blob:URL - the most fastet way :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't use a file:// URL, nor do you use any --allow... exceptions. Once you have a FileEntry, you fetch the binary data from the image and form it into a data URL, which you can use directly as an img src. See my answer to this question: [chrome packaged app image access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973989/chrome-packaged-app-image-access/22883650#22883650)

UPDATE: Given a File object (file), here's the code to set the src property of an image (img):

```
img.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);
```

If you have a FileEntry, you can get its File via the file() method.

Comment: It's better if you include even a small sample in this answer. OR mark this question as a duplicate if you feel it's redundant.

Comment: Your answer to this question points to the documentation (which I've looked at) which has me fetching the data via XHR, which I can't do because the images aren't being hosted by any webserver (locally).  Do you have a reference to how I go about doing what you're describing here (since it's different from your other answer).

Comment: See addition to my answer, above. Also, Rob W's answer is pretty much the same, except that you'll have to track down whether you still need the webkit prefix to the URL object.

Answer (score 1):

Are the assets in the user's Dropbox or yours? If they are yours, you should be able to get them using fetch after making them public.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "yours".  The assets are in the user's dropbox folder, the app is installed and run by the user. Who am "I" in this arrangement?