# Webview Status - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

Here is a brief project description:

I have created a packaged application for Chrome that allows members to scan in using a serial barcode scanner. These members have pictures on different servers based on their identification numbers. I am pulling the pictures in using a webview and it works good until one of the members does not have a picture on file. This displays an ugly 404 error in the webview.

I can not seem to find out how to get the status of a webview. Is there a way for me to find the status of the webview so that on the event of a 404 error I can dynamically change the content?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but why are you using a webview? It's straightforward to fetch and display an image if that's all you're trying to do. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external for example.

Comment: Unless they changed something I dont think you can call outside anything into a packaged app but through the webview.

Comment: No, that's never been the case. You can XHR freely from a Chrome App. As the linked documentation says, because of CSP "you can't directly reference external images, stylesheets, or fonts from an app page. Instead, you can use use cross-origin XMLHttpRequests to fetch these resources, and then serve them via blob: URLs."

Comment: Yes I figured that out. Now its functioning as needed. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches: As sowbug says, you can just display the image directly. How you do that is explained here: [chrome packaged app image access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973989/chrome-packaged-app-image-access/22883650#22883650). Or, if you really want to use a webview, you can determine that the image exists first via a call using XMLHttpRequest. The URL above explains how to do that also.